# Addressing lack of transcript due to early withdrawal in a graduate school application

Tags: graduate-admissions, transcript-of-records

I enrolled in a degree program at a university in my home country (~2nd world) immediately after finishing high school. However, I became dissatisfied with many aspects of the course and the university itself (corruption, plagiarism being largely ignored by assessors, lack of standardization in assessment metrics, etc) very quickly and decided to withdraw before completing the first academic year.

Later, I enrolled in a different program at a university in Western Europe and successfully completed my undergraduate studies. At the moment, I am in the process of drafting applications for graduate studies. However, it looks increasingly likely that the university in my home country will not be able to issue a transcript, as I withdrew prior to completion of a single year of study. Even if the university will be able to issue a transcript, the transcript will show 0 marks for all subjects I was meant to take that year. Naturally, I have no intention of trying to hide that I was enrolled in that program for several months. However, I am not certain how to address the issue in my applications whether or not the university will be able to issue a transcript. So,

1. Assuming that the university will not be able to issue a transcript, how and where should I explain this? In my CV? Should I contact the graduate admission offices explicitly?
2. Assuming that the university will be able to issue a transcript with 0 marks, how and where in my application should I explain this "failure"? :)

Note that most of my applications do not require a personal statement (only a statement of purpose or a research statement, along with a CV and the transcripts).

Comment: Failing all your classes is different than withdrawing, at least in the US system. What actually happened?

Comment: How long a gap was there? And this depends a lot on whether that university will issue any transcript and what it might say.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- As I explained, there is no clarity at the moment about what exactly they can/will issue. I am in the process of negotiation. Either way, for the second question, you can assume that the transcript will have "W"s instead of "0"s. I would still need to provide an explanation somewhere, somehow.

Comment: Well, sure, but explaining why you "failed" is different than just saying "it didn't work out."

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Yes, this makes sense. Perhaps, if you decide to answer, it may be best to assume the worst, i.e., the transcript will contain 0s (however, of course, technically, I withdrew from the course long before the end of the first academic year).

Comment: @Buffy Couldn't an answer to the question cover both cases? I am not yet certain what is and what isn't possible.

Comment: My first consideration is whether you need to mention it at all in the written materials. Knowing more about the transcript (and the gap) might help provide an answer.

Comment: @Buffy For the gap you can assume ~10 years since withdrawal. I can't say more about the transcript though.